# How to get the logs of an application from one container into another container in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

We are planning to implement Kubernetes application monitoring using Prometheus. Our application is running in apache and deployed to kubernetes cluster. We are developing Custom Apache exporter which will run in same POD as my application container & gather metrics from apache and push them to Prometheus. As part of this monitoring we need to parse access.log in apache to get number of 2xx, 3xx,4xx & 5xx requests. But Our application that is deployed in Kubernetes doesnt store any logs inside the POD, but it logs to STDOUT. So I can access logs from kubectl logs command. Now my Apache exporter that I am building is hosted in same POD as my application container. Now my question is How can i get application logs (access.log) to be present/accessible to  my apache exporter container, so that I can parse the logic and comeup with metrics like number of 2xx,3xx,4xx & 5xx.

Comment: You can try configuring your Apache to log to file instead of logging to STDOUT.

Comment: I'd recommend to store them in a volume and mount the volume in both containers.

Comment: I think Containerization standard is to push logs to STD OUT and not store in POD. We also push logs to Splunk/ELK. ALso if we store logs in POD and in some Volume then how can we push those logs to Splunk? We have Splunk forwarder also installed in all worker nodes which push logs to Splunk.

Because of above reasons we cannot have logs stored in POD & We cannot have logs mounted in volume which can be shared to both containers.

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes stores container's STDOUTs at `/var/logs/containers` and `/var/logs/pods` of each node in a format `POD_NAMESPACE_CONTAINER_CONTAINERID.log` and `NAMESPACE_POD_CONTAINERID/CONTAINER/*.log` respectively. These files will be deleted once the pod is evitced from the node.

You can mount either of them to your exporter pod to read logs. Problems are,

- `CONTAINER ID` is not available as an ENV in Kubernetes. We can't generate the file name and mount exactly the file that we want. We have to mount the entire `/var/log/containers/` or `/var/log/pods` directory.
- Mounting a writable `hostPath` is highly vulnerable in Kubernetes. So, make sure to set it as `readOnly` file system or configure `PodSecurityPolicy`.

YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
    resources: {}
  - image: busybox
    name: exporter
    command: ["cat"]
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/log/
      name: logs
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: logs
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/containers/
      # path: /var/log/pods/
      type: Directory
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

Logs

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx -n dev -c exporter sh -- ls /var/log | grep nginx
nginx_dev_exporter-41a2a80de1b899d1ee848378d2bf31285658bf86700671e560588ac69b2717b4.log
nginx_dev_nginx-e4c12df0c9dae129ed113f4195d750b447a570a686e3b5608e1af37ced788549.log
```

Comment: hey I can list the files in the container using ls /var/log command, but I cannot see content using cat command. It gives error No such file or directory. What might be the issue?

Comment: solved above issue.. you will also need to mount /var/lib/docker/containers

Answer (score 0):

Use a log aggregation tool, like loki for example, which is well integrated with kubernetes and grafana, then you can do all this parsing in a grafana dashboard and create the alarms there